# tag [remote-access] vs. [remote-control]

Tags: discussion, tags

As of the writing of this, there's [225 questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) tagged [remote-control](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) and 537 tagged [remote-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-access).

The [description on the "tag info" page for the latter](https://superuser.com/tags/remote-access/info) seems much more complete than [the info for the former tag](https://superuser.com/tags/remote-control/info).

Specifically what puzzles me is the snippet I bolded out:

> Gaining control to a computer or equipment while not necessarily being physically located near it. More specific tags include [remote-desktop] and [vnc]. **Not the same as [remote-access].**

So, I wonder: where they differ? And where do they overlap, if any?

Answer (score 6):

I think that the difference between is that [remote-control](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) is about having *control* of the system *remotelly*, while [remote-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-access) is about access to remote resources, ie. files, services, hardware, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that popped into my head was a recent conversation where I asked about Screen Sharing and someone suggested Remote Desktop.  I may be way off, but I would consider RDP "Remote Access" while I might consider TeamViewer/VNC "Remote Control".  I could actually see arguments for flipping that, but either way the point is that they are different in my opinion.